# How to subtract 1 day to file name which contains current date on Linux

Tags: linux

I have the following command (which works):

```
for f in /home/backups/*; do mv -n "$f" "${f}_$(date -r "$f" +'%Y%m%d')"; done
```

For example:
In `/home/backups` I have the file `backup`. Executing the command it renames to `backup_20180608` (the current date).

What I wish is subtracting 1 day. I mean the file should be `backup_20180607`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code that does not work. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split for better readability:

```
for f in /home/backups/*;
   do mv -n "$f" "${f}_$(date -d "$(date -r "$f") -1 days" +'%Y%m%d')";
done
```

The important part:

```
$(date -d "$(date -r "$f") -1 days" +'%Y%m%d')
```

[From](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) `man date`:

> -d, --date=STRING
>
> display time described by STRING, not 'now'

Here `STRING` will be that last modification time reported by `date -r "$f"`.

`- 1 days` subtracts one day from the date which will be formatted as `%Y%m%d`

---

One-liner for copy&paste:

```
for f in /home/backups/*; do mv -n "$f" "${f}_$(date -d "$(date -r "$f") -1 days" +'%Y%m%d')"; done
```